# Subquery joined with main query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to do a subquery, but need it's value to be based on the main query.

Basically, I am trying to get the `ID`, `Date`, and `Value` from a table, which we'll call `Orders`. However, in case there is no Value present on the specified date in there `WHERE` clause, then I want to know the date where the value was in (whether prior or post the specified date).

The falling query is wrong, but it might explain my logic:

```
SELECT 
   O.ID
  ,O.Date
  ,CASE
      WHEN O.Value IS NULL
      THEN
         (SELECT MAX(Date) 
          FROM Orders AS O1 
          WHERE O1.ID = O.ID
      ELSE O.Value END
   ) as Value
FROM Orders O
WHERE O.date = '2017-01-01'
```

I'm looking to get the following, for example:

```
ID    Value
001   100
002   300
003   12-30-2016
```

Comment: How it fails? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY/OUTER APPLY`, it is enabling you to query two or more correlated queries:

```
select 
       o.id
     , o.date
     , case when o.value is null then t.dt else o.value end as value
from orders o outer apply ( select o1.id, max(date) dt
                            from orders as o1 
                            where o1.id = o.id 
                            group by o1.id
                          ) t
where o.date = 2017-01-01
```

Comment: First time using Outer Apply, but it totally worked - thanks ^

Answer (score 1):

You just put the closing parens in the wrong place:

```
SELECT 
   O.ID
  ,O.Date
  ,CASE
      WHEN O.Value IS NULL
      THEN
         (SELECT MAX(Date) 
          FROM Orders AS O1 
          WHERE O1.ID = O.ID)
      ELSE O.Value
   END as Value
FROM Orders O
WHERE O.date = '2017-01-01'
```

or using COALESCE:

```
  ,COALESCE(O.Value
           ,( SELECT MAX(Date) 
              FROM Orders AS O1 
              WHERE O1.ID = O.ID
            )
           ) as Value
```

Of course you still might get an error due to non-matching datatypes, then cast both `O.Value` and the Scalar Subquery to a VarChar.